# Making use of Angularjs services

Tags: angularjs

I have this code within my `UserController`:

```
$scope.register = function() {
  //this.loading = true;

    $http.post('/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data) {
        alert("user added");
    });

};
```

but I'm sure I read somewhere that this kind of thing should go within a service. As I'm totally new to Angularjs could someone should me how to add this to a service and call it from my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is something like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('UserService', function UserService($http) {
    this.register = function register(data){
        return $http.post('/signup', data);
    };
};
.controller('RegisterCtrl', function RegisterCtrl(UserService) {
    var register = this;
    register.form = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    };
    register.submit = function(form) {
        var promise = UserService.register(register.form)(function(data) {
            alert("user added");
        });
        return promise;
    }
});
```